# Trapping WM_SETFOCUS in WindProc VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a user control that inherits from a base user control class.  On the user control that inherits this, I place a series of textboxes.  At runtime, I need to know when each control gets focus and loses focus.  To do this, I overrode WndProc in the base class, and am attempting to capture the messages there.  The problem I'm having is that I never receive WM_SETFOCUS or WM_KILLFOCUS within the message loop.

This is the WndProc:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
  Select Case m.Msg
    Case WM_SETFOCUS
      Debug.WriteLine(m.ToString())
    Case WM_KILLFOCUS
      Debug.WriteLine(m.ToString())
    Case Else
      Debug.Print("OTHER: " + m.ToString())
  End Select

  MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

I get a whole bunch of message for getting text and some other stuff, so I know that I'm getting there.  It just never stops on WM_SETFOCUS or WM_KILLFOCUS.

What am I not doing correctly.

Comment: how is using the standard Enter and Leave events not enough?

Comment: I am trying to find a generic way to do this.  I have many textbox controls on one of these user controls.  I need to trap focus on each of the text boxes.

Comment: I suppose that I could add some control to the Load of my base class, and add event handlers for each of the textboxes.  That would give me the functionality that I need.

Comment: "What am I not doing correctly."  You're not in the right WndProc().  Those messages will be sent to the TextBoxes, not the UserControl.  Either list all of those TextBoxes after the `Handles` clause for the respective events, or wire them up dynamically in the Load() event as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Quick example of wiring up all TextBoxes in the UserControl:

```
Public Class UserControl1

    Private Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        WireTBs(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub WireTBs(ByVal cont As Control)
        For Each ctl As Control In cont.Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
                Dim TB As TextBox = DirectCast(ctl, TextBox)
                AddHandler TB.GotFocus, AddressOf TB_GotFocus
                AddHandler TB.LostFocus, AddressOf TB_LostFocus
            ElseIf ctl.HasChildren Then
                WireTBs(ctl)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub TB_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim TB As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        ' ... do something with "TB" ...
        Debug.Print("GotFocus: " & TB.Name)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TB_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim TB As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        ' ... do something with "TB" ...
        Debug.Print("LostFocus: " & TB.Name)
    End Sub

End Class
```